# "Unable to open this file on your device" : How to download the file to Android?

Tags: downloading, intents, line

Using the Android app [LINE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_(software)), a friend sent me a file, and I would like to download it.

Upon tapping the file, the download takes a few minutes then displays:

[image: Unable to open this file on your device. Please try again from the PC version of LINE]

I don't have access to a PC.

I can't find the file in my Android's folders `Downloads` nor `Downloads/LINE` nor `data/jp.naver.line.android/temp/temp_download`.

**Question**: How to get the file?

- Maybe the file is saved somewhere in a temporary or internal folder?
- Maybe I can use an app that would pretend to open the file, but in fact save it? I tried this trick with ToGoZip but it did not work, ToGoZip just said it could not open the file.
- Any other trick is welcome! The file is a .key presentation, if that matters.

Comment: Did you check the log to see if LINE fires an intent to ask the system for apps which can handle this type of file? Btw what type of file is it?

Comment: I will check, thanks! The file is a .key presentation, if that matters.